# Consolibyte:MySQL Mirror sync is not working for invoices and payments

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks

We are using the MySQL Mirror sync method to keep QuickBook desktop and MySQL in sync. QuickBook data is being imported and synced with MySql but mysql changes did't synced completely with QuickBook desktop.

we are testing the following scenarios and not seeing data being sync'd from MySQL -> QB

**For "Invoice", following cases were tested**

Case 1

- Updated a recored in qb_invoice table (MySQL database).
- After 15 minutes QWC run the sync process.
- Updates made in mysql are not present in QBD

Case 2

- Created a recored in qb_invoice table (MySQL Database).
- After 15 minutes QWC run the sync process.
- Newly created invoice is not present in QBD

Case 3

- Made two transactions of  $50 for a invoice that was already synced
  in mysql database. In QBD $100 was adjusted for invoice and remaining
  balance of invoice was updated.
- After 15 minutes QWC run the sync process.
- Consolibyte synced new transactions in mysql database (
  qb_receivepayment , qb_receivepayment_appliedtotxn ).
- In Invoice table, Remaining balance is not updated in qb_invoice
  table (MySQL database).

**For "Payments", following cases were tested**

Case 1

- Updated a recored in qb_receivepayment and
  qb_receivepayment_appliedtotxn tables (MySQL database).
- After 15 minutes QWC run the sync process.
- Updates made in mysql is not present in QuickBook.

Case 2

- Created a new recored in qb_receivepayment and
  qb_receivepayment_appliedtotxn tables (MySQL database).
- After 15 minutes QWC run the sync process.
- New created payment is not present in QuickBook

**This is the mirror code I am using to sync.**

```
<?php

// I always program in E_STRICT error mode with error reporting turned on... 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Set the include path
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../QuickBooks.php';

// You should make sure this matches the time-zone QuickBooks is running in
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
}

// The username and password the Web Connector will use to connect with
$username = 'Admin';
$password = 'abc123';


$dsn = 'mysqli://root:@localhost/quickbooks_sql';

// If the database has not been initialized, we need to initialize it (create 
//  schema and set up the username/password, etc.)
if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    // It takes a really long time to build the schema... 
    set_time_limit(0);

    $driver_options = array(
        );

    $init_options = array(
        'quickbooks_sql_enabled' => true, 
        );

    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn, $driver_options, $init_options);
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $username, $password);

    exit;
}

// What mode do we want to run the mirror in? 
//$mode = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::MODE_READONLY;        // Read from QuickBooks only (no data will be pushed back to QuickBooks)
//$mode = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::MODE_WRITEONLY;       // Write to QuickBooks only (no data will be copied into the SQL database)
$mode = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::MODE_READWRITE;     // Keep both QuickBooks and the database in sync, reading and writing changes back and forth)

// What should we do if a conflict is found? (a record has been changed by another user or process that we're trying to update)
$conflicts = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::CONFLICT_LOG;

// What should we do with records deleted from QuickBooks? 
//$delete = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::DELETE_REMOVE;      // Delete the record from the database too
$delete = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL::DELETE_FLAG;      // Just flag it as deleted

// Hooks (optional stuff)
$hooks = array();

$soap_options = array();

// 
$handler_options = array(
    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false,
    );

// 
$driver_options = array();

$ops = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_SALESTAXITEM, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_SALESTAXCODE, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CUSTOMER, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_VENDOR, 

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_INVENTORYITEM, 

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_TEMPLATE, 

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CUSTOMERTYPE, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_VENDORTYPE, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_ESTIMATE, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_INVOICE, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CLASS, 

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_PAYMENTITEM,
    /*
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_INVENTORYITEM, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_NONINVENTORYITEM, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_SERVICEITEM, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_SHIPMETHOD, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_PAYMENTMETHOD, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_TERMS, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_PRICELEVEL, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_ITEM, 
    */
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_RECEIVEPAYMENT,

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_PAYMENTMETHOD,

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_SALESORDER,

    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_COMPANY, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_HOST, 
    QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_PREFERENCES,
    );

$ops_misc = array(      // For fetching inventory levels, deleted transactions, etc. 
    QUICKBOOKS_DERIVE_INVENTORYLEVELS,
    QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_DELETEDLISTS,
    QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_DELETEDTRANSACTIONS,
    // 'nothing', 
    );

// 
$sql_options = array(
    'only_import' => $ops,
    'only_add' => $ops, 
    'only_modify' => $ops, 
    'only_misc' => $ops_misc, 
    );

// 
$callback_options = array();

// $dsn_or_conn, $how_often, $mode, $conflicts, $users = null, 
//  $map = array(), $onerror = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array()
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server_SQL(
    $dsn, 
    '1 minute', 
    $mode, 
    $conflicts, 
    $delete,
    $username, 
    array(), 
    array(), 
    $hooks, 
    QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP, 
    QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN, 
    QUICKBOOKS_WSDL,
    $soap_options, 
    $handler_options, 
    $driver_options,
    $sql_options, 
    $callback_options);
$Server->handle(true, true);
```

**How we can sync invoices and payments data from MySQL to QuickBook Desktop?**

I have narrow down the problem and now trying to sync a SalesOrder from MySQL to QBD.

For this I have tested this scenerio

- Created a sales order in qb_salesorder table(MySQL). This is the sql query.

  INSERT INTO `qb_salesorder` (`qbsql_id`, `qbsql_username_id`, `qbsql_external_id`, `TxnID`, `TimeCreated`, `TimeModified`, `EditSequence`, `TxnNumber`, `Customer_ListID`, `Customer_FullName`, `Class_ListID`, `Class_FullName`, `Template_ListID`, `Template_FullName`, `TxnDate`, `RefNumber`, `BillAddress_Addr1`, `BillAddress_Addr2`, `BillAddress_Addr3`, `BillAddress_Addr4`, `BillAddress_Addr5`, `BillAddress_City`, `BillAddress_State`, `BillAddress_PostalCode`, `BillAddress_Country`, `BillAddress_Note`, `BillAddressBlock_Addr1`, `BillAddressBlock_Addr2`, `BillAddressBlock_Addr3`, `BillAddressBlock_Addr4`, `BillAddressBlock_Addr5`, `ShipAddress_Addr1`, `ShipAddress_Addr2`, `ShipAddress_Addr3`, `ShipAddress_Addr4`, `ShipAddress_Addr5`, `ShipAddress_City`, `ShipAddress_State`, `ShipAddress_PostalCode`, `ShipAddress_Country`, `ShipAddress_Note`, `ShipAddressBlock_Addr1`, `ShipAddressBlock_Addr2`, `ShipAddressBlock_Addr3`, `ShipAddressBlock_Addr4`, `ShipAddressBlock_Addr5`, `PONumber`, `Terms_ListID`, `Terms_FullName`, `DueDate`, `SalesRep_ListID`, `SalesRep_FullName`, `FOB`, `ShipDate`, `ShipMethod_ListID`, `ShipMethod_FullName`, `Subtotal`, `ItemSalesTax_ListID`, `ItemSalesTax_FullName`, `SalesTaxPercentage`, `SalesTaxTotal`, `TotalAmount`, `IsManuallyClosed`, `IsFullyInvoiced`, `Memo`, `CustomerMsg_ListID`, `CustomerMsg_FullName`, `IsToBePrinted`, `IsToBeEmailed`, `CustomerSalesTaxCode_ListID`, `CustomerSalesTaxCode_FullName`, `Other`, `qbsql_discov_datetime`, `qbsql_resync_datetime`, `qbsql_modify_timestamp`, `qbsql_last_hash`, `qbsql_last_qbxml`, `qbsql_last_errnum`, `qbsql_last_errmsg`, `qbsql_enqueue_datetime`, `qbsql_dequeue_datetime`, `qbsql_audit_amount`, `qbsql_audit_modified`, `qbsql_to_sync`, `qbsql_to_delete`, `qbsql_to_skip`, `qbsql_to_void`, `qbsql_flag_deleted`, `qbsql_flag_skipped`, `qbsql_flag_voided`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '56BF-104531114-2018-02-09', '2018-02-09 04:40:00', '2018-02-09 04:40:00', '1544879385', '1422', '410000-1040150879', 'Dunning\'s Pool Depot, Inc ltd.:Big City Store #002', NULL, NULL, '110000-1048186767', 'Custom Sales Order', '2018-11-05', '8889', 'Pool Depot, Inc.', 'Bronx Store', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Pool Depot, Inc.', 'Bronx Store', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Pool Depot, Inc.', 'Bronx Store', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Pool Depot, Inc.', 'Bronx Store', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2019-11-05', '30000-1046217599', 'DR', NULL, '2018-11-05', NULL, NULL, '900.00', NULL, NULL, '0.00000', '0.00', '900.00', '0', '0', NULL, '40000-1049237419', 'We appreciate this opportunity!', '1', '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-02-09 05:00:00', '2018-02-09 05:00:00', '2018-02-09 05:00:00', NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')
- Created a sales order line item in qb_salesorder_salesorderline table(MySQL). This is SQL Query.

  INSERT INTO `qb_salesorder_salesorderline` (`qbsql_id`, `qbsql_username_id`, `qbsql_external_id`, `SalesOrder_TxnID`, `SortOrder`, `TxnLineID`, `Item_ListID`, `Item_FullName`, `Descrip`, `Quantity`, `UnitOfMeasure`, `OverrideUOMSet_ListID`, `OverrideUOMSet_FullName`, `Rate`, `RatePercent`, `Class_ListID`, `Class_FullName`, `Amount`, `InventorySite_ListID`, `InventorySite_FullName`, `SerialNumber`, `LotNumber`, `SalesTaxCode_ListID`, `SalesTaxCode_FullName`, `Invoiced`, `IsManuallyClosed`, `Other1`, `Other2`, `qbsql_discov_datetime`, `qbsql_resync_datetime`, `qbsql_modify_timestamp`, `qbsql_last_hash`, `qbsql_last_qbxml`, `qbsql_last_errnum`, `qbsql_last_errmsg`, `qbsql_enqueue_datetime`, `qbsql_dequeue_datetime`, `qbsql_audit_amount`, `qbsql_audit_modified`, `qbsql_to_sync`, `qbsql_to_delete`, `qbsql_to_skip`, `qbsql_to_void`, `qbsql_flag_deleted`, `qbsql_flag_skipped`, `qbsql_flag_voided`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '56BF-104531114-2018-02-09', '0', '616B-1048186860', '670004-1044572237', 'Installation Labor', 'Installation, Initial Labor', '3.00000', 'hour', '8000000A-1156281862', 'Hour', '300.00000', NULL, NULL, NULL, '900.00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '20000-1011136881', 'Non', '0.00000', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-02-09 05:00:00', '2018-02-09 05:00:00', '2018-02-09 05:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')
- After 15 minutes QWC run the sync process.
- Sales Order is not Visible in QBD

**We have to sync invoice and payments from MySql to QBD. How can we achieve this**

Comment: For starters, post your code so we can actually help you.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I have added the code.